# PyGame Sound шумы при воспроизведении фрагментов звука, в чем проблема?

Tags: pygame, wav

Пишу приложение для создания анимации, есть необходимость **нарезки звука на фрагменты** соответствующие кадрам анимации. Для этих целей использую **PyGame mixer Sound**. При воспроизведении этих фрагментов **возникают шумы**.
При сборке фрагментов в новый звук происходит следующее:

- если собирать от первого до последнего, то звук получается **чистый**
- если НЕ от первого до последнего, получается **грязный или один шум**
- если от первого НЕ до последнего, получается ***чистый*** звук

Причем такое происходит не со всеми **WAV** файлами, с одними вообще нет проблем, а с другими всё вышеописанное.
**В чем причина и как с ней бороться?**

**Дополнение:** заметил, что на шумы влияет изменение переменной `SPF` (количество семплов на кадр), вероятно имеет влияние длина оглавления файла или длина семплов.

---

[Ссылка на звук с которым НЕТ ПРОБЛЕМ.](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/L2mghW_IWy0TMg)

[Ссылка на звук  С ПРОБЛЕМАМИ](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/xuBECjax6-p0Rw)

Пример воспроизводимого кода:

```
import os.path
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel,QFileDialog, QApplication
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.mixer import Sound

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        mixer.init()
        self.label = QLabel('Click me!', self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('font-size: 20px')
        self.label.setGeometry(10,10,480,280)
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.setFixedHeight(300)

        # необходимые переменные
        self.FPS = 12  # предустановленная скорость кадров в секунду
        self.Frame_Count = 25  # предустановленное количество кадров
        self.Current_Frame = 0  # текущий кадр
        self.Frame_List = []  # список для нарезанных звуков в кадры
        self.collect_arr = None # переменная для сборки фрагментов звука
        self.interval = [0,24] # значения диапазона для сборки фрагментов звука от 0 до 24

        self.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.Frame_List = []  # очищаем список
        self.collect_arr = None # очищаем сборку
        PathTuple = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open file', '', "wav file (*.wav)")
        if PathTuple[0] != '':
            txt_lbl = os.path.basename(PathTuple[0] + '\n')
            snd = Sound(PathTuple[0]) # объект звук из файла
            snd_arr = snd.get_raw() # получаем битовый массив звука
            samples = len(snd_arr) # длина - количество семплов
            txt_lbl += str(samples) + ' семплов\n'
            duration = snd.get_length()  # продолжительнось звука
            txt_lbl += str(duration) + ' длительность\n'
            SPF = int((samples / duration) / self.FPS)  # семплов в одном кадре
            txt_lbl += str(SPF) + ' семплов в кадре\n'

            for i in range(self.Frame_Count): # цикл от 0 до количества кадров
                if i == 0: # добавляем первый фрагмент звука
                    self.Frame_List.append(snd_arr[ :SPF])  # добавляем в список срез массива для каждого кадра
                self.Frame_List.append(snd_arr[i*SPF : (i+1)*SPF])  # далее ОТ значения i ПО i+1

                if i >= self.interval[0] and i <= self.interval[1]: # делаем сборку из фрагментов в заданном диапазоне
                    if self.collect_arr == None:
                        self.collect_arr = snd_arr[i*SPF : (i+1)*SPF]
                    else:
                        self.collect_arr = self.collect_arr + snd_arr[i*SPF : (i+1)*SPF]

            self.timer = QTimer() # создаем таймер
            self.timer.start(84) # запускаем с интервалом соответствующим 12 кадрам в секунду
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.play_animation_sound) # отправляем сигнал в слот
            txt_lbl += 'ВОСПРОИЗВЕДЕНИЕ\n'

            self.label.setText(str(txt_lbl))  # выводим информацию в лейбл

    def play_animation_sound(self):
        Sound(self.Frame_List[self.Current_Frame]).play() # воспроизводим фрагмент текущего кадра
        self.Current_Frame += 1 # переходим в следующий кадр
        if self.Current_Frame >= 25: # по достижении последнего кадра
            self.timer.stop() # останавливаем таймер
            self.Current_Frame = 0 # возвращаемся в нулевой кадр
            self.label.setText(self.label.text() + '\nВоспроизведение сборки')  # выводим информацию в лейбл
            Sound(self.collect_arr).play() # воспроизводим сборку диапазона

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName("Window")
window = Window()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

В чем причина возникновения шумов - я так и не разобрался, но проблема устранилась следующим образом: вместо округления `SPF` с помощью `int` нужно использовать `round`.

Строку `SPF = int((samples / duration) / self.FPS)  # семплов в одном кадре`

заменить на `SPF = round((samples / duration) / self.FPS)  # семплов в одном кадре`

Для примера, если без округления получилось **14699,99976238...**

`int` просто обрезает дробную часть **14699**

а `round` округляет по математическим правилам **14700**